# CSS responsive overlayed images

Tags: html, image, css, responsive-design

I have two images which need to be over each other. The images have to also be responsive and therefore have a percentage width and height.

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="res/bigger.png/>
    <img src="res/smaller.png class="icon"/>
</div>

.container {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:blue;
  postion:relative;
}
.container img {
   max-width:100%;
   max-heihgt: 100%;
   height: auto;
   width: auto;
}
.icon {
   position: relative;
   top: -70%;
   left: 20%;
   z-index: 50;
   width: 10% !important;
   height: auto !important;
}
```

As the two images do not have the same proportions when re-sized the smaller image which is on top of the bigger image will lose its position relative to the bigger image. How could I maintain the position of the smaller image relative to the bigger image when I re-size the page? 
An example of this problem could be found here http://jsfiddle.net/5YQFV/

Answer (score 0):

How about, instead of using two images you would replace the largest image with a container like this

```
<div class="the-gang">
  <img src="res/smaller.png" />
</div>
```

And then set the position of the container to `position:relative` but the position of the smaller image to `position:absolute` like this

```
.the-gang{
  position:relative;
  width:100px;
  height:75px;
}

.the-gang img{
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
}
```

This way the smallest image will always stay where you place it, as the absolute position will be relative to it's container.
The possible disadvantage is that you have to set minimal height and width of the parent container, but the advantage is that it will be done purely in CSS and no javascript will have to be used.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle as you have explained: http://jsfiddle.net/5YQFV/2/ The problem with this example is that the div does not resize to the size of the image and therefore the smaller image will still move as the container div is resized

Comment: Do you mean that the container doesn't resize to the size of the background image? If so, then you have to use javascript to get the size of the background as css is not aware of it's size and cannot resize the container.